# Nemo Action on Desktop not appearing

Tags: linux, linux-mint, nemo

I have this `.nemo_action` file in `~/.local/share/nemo/actions`, but it does not have any effect:

```
[Nemo Action]                                                                                        
Active=true                                                                                             
Exec=/usr/bin/xfce4-display-settings                                                                    
Icon-Name=preferences-desktop-display                                                                
Selection=none                                                                                       
Extensions=any;                                                                                      
Conditions=desktop;                                                                                  
Name=Change Displays                                                                                 
Comment=Rearrange displays
```

I've also tried varying `Extensions` to `none` and varying the path of `Exec`, but nothing shows up. The [reference file](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/blob/master/files/usr/share/nemo/actions/sample.nemo_action) says this should work AFAICT, and online guides say that there shouldn't be any need to restart the system, re-initialize Nemo, etc.

So what's wrong?

Comment: Please do not mutilate the question. [Registered users can delete their posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50271/355310). This is the right way to delete.